# How to join tables to show product even though the other table has no such product data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I used to post this question to SO however, the answer I was given displayed all the table from tbl_product not from tbl_inventory and tbl_reserve. So could you please help. Thank you very much.

```
    tbl_inventory
    inv_id | pd_id | inv_qty_act |  inv_date | inv_note
     1     |  001  |  120        |  20-Sep-12| 
     2     |  003  |  387        |  1-Oct-12 |

    tbl_reserve
    res_id | cust_id | res_date | res_duedate | pd_id | res_qty | if_sent | res_note
     3     |  10     | 01-Oct-12|   17-Oct-12 |  001  |  135    |         | 
     4     |  9      | 01-Oct-12|   24-Oct-12 |  001  |  253    |         |
     5     |  22     | 01-Oct-12|   17-Oct-12 |  001  |  132    |         | 
     6     |  2      | 01-Oct-12|   24-Oct-12 |  002  |  446    |         | 


    tbl_product
    pd_id  | pd_name 
      001  |  des1
      002  |  des2
      003  |  des3

    tbl_pdtn_startup
    pdtn_st_id | pd_id | pdtn_qty_est
    2         |  002  |  200
    3         |  003  |  100
```

**Output that I want :** 
To make it easier what I really want  are report that show : 
1. product name (pd_name) 
2. qty of finished products (inv_qty_act)
3. estimated qty that was in production (pdtn_qty_est)
4. and sum of product that being reserved from customers (Sum(res_qty). 
As for the total field, I can have it calculated from the code. Thank you very much

```
     pd_id| pd_name| inv_qty_act|pdtn_qty_est| Sum(res_qty)| Total[(inv_qty_est) - Sum(res_qty)]
      001 | des1   |    120     |   0        |   520       |     -400 -->(120-520)
      002 | des2   |     0      |   200      |   446       |     -446 -->(0-446)
      003 | des3   |    387     |   100      |     0       |      387
```

[image: desired outcome]

outcome that i really want are records that only in "Red" rectangles

Answer (score 1):

To join more than two tables in Access SQL, you have to put each `JOIN` in parentheses:

```
SELECT
    tbl_product.pd_id,
    tbl_product.pd_name,
    tbl_inventory.inv_qty_act,
    tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_qty_est,
    Sum(tbl_reserve.res_qty) AS [Sum(res_qty)]
FROM 
    ((tbl_product 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_inventory ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_inventory.pd_id) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_pdtn_startup ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_reserve ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_reserve.pd_id
GROUP BY
    tbl_product.pd_id,
    tbl_product.pd_name,
    tbl_inventory.inv_qty_act,
    tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_qty_est;
```

If you're not sure about the correct syntax in Access, just build your query in the query designer and then switch to SQL View. The query designer will add the parentheses automatically.

One more thing:
In your desired output, the missing values in the `inv_qty_act`, `pdtn_qty_est` and `Sum(res_qty)` columns are zero. In a vanilla `LEFT JOIN` query, these will be `NULL` instead.

So my above query actually returns this:

```
 pd_id| pd_name| inv_qty_act|pdtn_qty_est| Sum(res_qty)| ...
  001 | des1   |    120     |   NULL     |   520       | ...
  002 | des2   |    NULL    |   200      |   446       | ...
  003 | des3   |    387     |   100      |   NULL      | ...

                     ^           ^            ^
                     |           |            |
                     |___ NULL instead of 0 __|
```

If you want to get `0` instead of `NULL`, you have to use the [`Nz()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172237%28v=office.11%29.aspx) function to convert the `NULL` values to zero.
Instead of `SELECT column`, just use `SELECT Nz(column, 0)`.

So the final query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    tbl_product.pd_id,
    tbl_product.pd_name,
    nz([inv_qty_act],0),
    nz([pdtn_qty_est],0),
    Sum(nz([res_qty],0)) AS [Sum(res_qty)]
FROM 
    ((tbl_product 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_inventory ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_inventory.pd_id) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_pdtn_startup ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_reserve ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_reserve.pd_id
GROUP BY
    tbl_product.pd_id,
    tbl_product.pd_name,
    tbl_inventory.inv_qty_act,
    tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_qty_est;
```

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, try this:

```
SELECT
    tbl_product.pd_id,
    tbl_product.pd_name,
    nz([inv_qty_act],0),
    nz([pdtn_qty_est],0),
    Sum(nz([res_qty],0)) AS [Sum(res_qty)]
FROM 
    ((tbl_product 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_inventory ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_inventory.pd_id) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_pdtn_startup ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_pdtn_startup.pd_id) 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_reserve ON tbl_product.pd_id = tbl_reserve.pd_id
GROUP BY
    tbl_product.pd_id,
    tbl_product.pd_name,
    tbl_inventory.inv_qty_act,
    tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_qty_est
HAVING
    tbl_inventory.inv_qty_act IS NOT NULL
    or tbl_pdtn_startup.pdtn_qty_est IS NOT NULL
```

The query is the same like above, only the last three lines (the `HAVING` clause) are new.
All products that are neither in `tbl_inventory` or `tbl_pdtn_startup` are ignored.
Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you for your kindly clarify this for me. But may be I haven't explained clear enough.<br> What I really want is product records that was found in either tbl_inventory or tbl_reserve. However with this SQL statement all the product records in (tbl_product) were retrieved even though there were not in tbl_inventory or tbl_reserve. (I've put my captured outcome to my question for more clarification). Could you please help me solve this again. Thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, I guess I understood what you mean. I just edited my answer!

Comment: Only product in tbl_inventory and tbl_reserve are what I want. Btw, this new sql statement cause the sum(res_qty) unfunctioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Join to  show product even though the other table has no such product